# Compatibility problems with jQuery Mobile 1.0 and UI 1.8.16 DatePicker icons

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, datepicker

I'm using jQuery Mobile and it works OK, I'm also using the 'old' jQuery UI DatePicker (not the mobile one) but I've noticed that the month navigation button icons on the date picker are wrong. To correct that problem I can change the order of the stylesheets but then I lose the data-theme icons from the mobile stuff.

Here's a JSFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/MXBYH/

Has anyone come across this before? Anyone got a solution?

Comment: Any specific reason you are using jQuery UI rather than a mobile-optimized solution? Customizing a jQuery UI build to just have the `Datepicker` component is still a 44KB JS file (not to mention the 24KB of CSS).

Comment: @Jasper Not really, only that I'm used to it and there doesn't seem to be a jQuery (by the jQuery folks) mobile DatePicker available yet.

Comment: http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/ This is an excellent Datepicker that has been optimized for jQuery Mobile 1.0. No, it's not from the jQuery Mobile team but it doesn't look like they are going to get to this for a while. Besides the code-weight (only 10KB minified) this is a good choice because it doesn't have the problems you are running into with class clashing issues.

Comment: http://mobiscroll.com/ Is another one I've used but it's code weights in a bit heavier at approx. 40KB minified.

Comment: I did look at the jtsage one, and it looks good, but I couldn't see how to change the buttons (plus & minus) for months to left & right arrows. Maybe I'll need to revisit it now I have a problem with the jQuery UI one. I'll check out the mobiscroll one. Thanks

Comment: Try Mobi Pick, an Android-style datepicker widget for jQuery Mobile: http://mobipick.sustainablepace.net/

Comment: K. Bob - i've not had a request to change the +/- buttons yet - it's not a bad idea, i can probably drop it in tonight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the moment, I've gone with the jtSage DateBox from http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/
The month next/prev button icons were hardcoded but I've made them options and it looks like it will work OK for me, still a bit to do with adjusting the pop-up positioning and a few other UI tweaks but it looks like it should be an acceptable solution.

The MobiScroll and MobiPick are just too 'androidy' for me at the moment.

Comment: Heh - that's what I get for not reading your answer before commenting above - anyway, changes/enhancements are always welcome if you decide you want to send your changes back to me.

Comment: @J.T.Sage I've made a couple of small changes, making the icons options and positioning the popup under the element, the popup seemed to move once (upwards) after the first popup before I made my change. I also dropped the border width of the popup to 1px in CSS. I'm still rooting about to see what else I need it to do but for so far so good - it's a nice little datepicker - thanks.